# Database structure for product attributes on orders

Tags: mysql, database-design

I'm making a POS and currently kind of stuck on the order proccess due to the product attributes.

As of now the DB looks something like this:

`tbl_products`

`tbl_attributes (attr id, name, extra price)`

`tbl_sales ( where i store the time, total price etc)`

`tbl_salelines ( where i store what items have being order for a certain sale).`

Problem is storing the attributes for an item order.
There isn't a fix amount of attributes one item can have. It could go from 1 to 10-15
therefor i don't think making some columns in the tbl_salelines with `attr_1` `attr_2` etc etc would solve this.

How should i approach this?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use a foreign key in tbl_attributes to youre tbl_salelines table. So you can have 1 saleline and for that saleline you can add multiple attributes which have a relation to the saleline?

Example:

```
tbl_saleline 1

Id -> 1    

tbl_attributes

**Attribute 1**
Id -> 1
name -> 'attribute 1'
**SaleLine_Id  -> 1 (FK->tbl_saleline)**

**Attribute 2**
Id -> 2
name -> 'attribute 2'
**SaleLine_Id -> 1  (FK->tbl_saleline)**
```